# Question on spectral sequence connecting Ext and Tor

Tags: homological-algebra, spectral-sequences

After many years of avoiding spectral sequences I have run into one that I can’t seem to avoid.  I have very limited understanding of what convergence of spectral sequences really means and I am hoping somebody can give me a concrete description of what this spectral sequence is telling me in my particular setup.

The spectral sequence is Theorem 10.62 in Rotman’s book on homological algebra (modulo correcting what I believe is a typo).  I think it can also be found in a slight variant in Cartan-Eilenberg. My setup is more specialized, which I am hoping will make it easier to understand what this means.

Let $R$ and $S$ be finite dimensional algebras over a field $K$. I work with left modules.  $S$-$R$-bimodules are assumed to have the same $K$-vector space structure from the action on both sides (i.e., are $S\otimes_K R^{op}$-modules). Also all modules and bimodules finite dimensional.

Then, according to Rotman, if $B$ is an $S$-$R$-bimodule and $C$ is an $S$-module such that $\mathrm{Ext}^i_S(B\otimes_R P,C)=0$ for every $i\geq 1$ when $P$ is a projective $R$-module, then there is a convergent 3rd quadrant spectral sequence

$$\mathrm{Ext}^p_S(\mathrm{Tor}^R_q(B,A),C)\Rightarrow_p \mathrm{Ext}^n_R(A,\mathrm{Hom}_S(B,C))$$
for every $R$-module $A$.

Since all these $\mathrm{Ext}$ are $K$-vector spaces all filtrations can be turned into vector space direct sums and so my vague understanding is that I should be able to express $\mathrm{Ext}^n_R(A,\mathrm{Hom}_S(B,C))$ as some sort of vector space direct sum related to $\mathrm{Ext}^p_S(\mathrm{Tor}^R_q(B,A),C)$.  But what exactly do I get?  Is it the case $$\mathrm{Ext}^n_R(A,\mathrm{Hom}_S(B,C))\cong \bigoplus_{p+q=n}\mathrm{Ext}^p_S(\mathrm{Tor}^R_q(B,A),C)$$
at least under some weaker hypotheses than $C$ is injective (for which I don’t need spectral sequences)?  If it helps, in my particular set up $B$ is free as a left $S$-module but not even flat as a right $R$-module.

I'd be happy to understand the special case where there is a surjective ring homomorphism $R\to S$ and $B=S$ so that the bimodule structure is the obvious one and this is the change of ring spectral sequence.

Comment: I could not digest exactly all the details, but in this very general setting (concerning the total degree $n$) we could write the isomorphism $\cong$ after the "what exactly do i get" question in the case of a corresponding degeneration in / after the second sheet of the spectral sequence. Else, taking further homology pieces w.r.t. $d^2$, $d^3$, ... (till these differentials may want to point from/to outside the third quadrant) will may cut some some piece of cake at each step from the $K$-vector spaces present in the second sheet. This was just a quick comment. I would test on a toy example.

Comment: You are only given the $E^2$-page of the spectral sequence, which converges (in some sense...) to those $\mathrm{Ext}$-groups. A priori, you cannot that say much about the limit in terms of the $E^2$-page. Regarding your very last comment, maybe look at [this preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/0707.3210).

Comment: @Pedro, thanks. I figured it was to naive to hope that I didn't need higher pages but I don't really understand spectral sequences.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg What references are you using? The point is that the "limit" of a spectral sequence say a of a filtered complex $C$ is $\mathrm{gr}_F H(C)$ where $F$ is a filtration one can cook up by hand from the filtration coming from $C$. Then usually $E^1$ is "just" $H(\mathrm{gr}_F(C))$, and for the whole set of (a priori infinitely many) pages of the sequence, you are slowly interchanging $\mathrm{gr}$ and $H$ (and you do not even get $H$ on the nose...!). There are in fact explicit descriptions of $E^r$ for a fixed $r$, that may or may not be illuminating. Have you seen them?

Comment: McCleary has [a book](https://people.math.rochester.edu/faculty/doug/otherpapers/McCleary-UGSS.pdf) which is very nice.

Comment: @Pedro, I looked at Rotman and Weibel.  I was hoping that for one particular spectral sequence what I was working over finite dimensional algebras it would be possible to get some sort of concrete description of what this means without having to understand the full machinery of spectral sequences but I guess that is not the case